# Unable to use react hooks with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using a class component as a parent for my functional components, using a useState hook while rendering the components with react-router crash the app, however, if the components are placed normally in the parent class component the app compiles fine.

[error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4lKn.png

this does NOT WORK:

```js
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' render={FrontPage}/>
       </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const FrontPage = () => {

  const [a, b] = useState('')

  return (
      <div> hello world </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

this WORKS

```js
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
//import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <FrontPage/>
    );
  }
}

const FrontPage = () => {

  const [a, b] = useState('')

  return (
      <div> hello world </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What error do you get and where?

Comment: In your `Route`, try using the `component` prop instead of the `render` prop. `component={FrontPage}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Route exact path='/' render={FrontPage}/>
```

That's not the correct way to use the `render` prop. If you just want to pass in a component, you can use the component prop as in:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={FrontPage}/>
```

If you want to use the render prop, you need to pass in a function:

```
<Route exact path='/' render={routeProps => <FrontPage {...routeProps} />}/>
```